# Find files containing multiple keywords with searchmonkey

Tags: search, text, searchmonkey

I want to find all files containing *all* of a list of keywords, for example `word1`, `word2`, `word3`. Note that I don't want to restrict the search to files containing the string `word1 word2 word3`, where all the words appear consecutively. I want to find *all* files that contain *all* these words, but in any place in the file.

Is there an option to get this done with searchmonkey?

Or an alternative software?

Comment: Literally a list or only some, say 5 or 7 keywords?

Comment: @ADDB Say 5 to 10. I'll type them manually, so it's not that many